# Zonal maximum at a specific location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics, flow-accumulation

I have 50,000 polygon shapefile, each polygon is a small community.
I have a flow accumulation raster.

I need to extract just the maximum cell (max flow accumulation) for each polygon.

Now if I run a zonal maximum it fills the polygon with the maximum flow accumulation value.

I need just the cell with the highest value returned not the entire zone.

I could do a zonal maximum and then subtract the original raster and I think all values that equal 0 would be what I want.

To be clear. I want just the cell with the highest value in each zone returned as a raster cell or even as a point (not the entire zone populated with the value).

ArcGIS solution preferred.
Model Builder fine.
ArcPY ok.

Comment: I think Nahas has the correct answer but if you have this raster "Now if I run a zonal maximum it fills the polygon with the maximum flow accumulation value" and this raster "I could do a zonal maximum and then subtract the original raster and I think all values that equal 0 would be what I want.". Just Reclassify the second raster (all data will be 0 and 0 will be 1) and apply the Times command from toolbox, raster 1 vs the reclassified raster 2.

Comment: nice I see it, let me try Nahas first then this second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Esri's support site : [HowTo:  Create points representing the highest or lowest elevations within polygon features](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41050)

Just replace the elevation raster by the Flow Accumulation raster.

> 1. Identify the value of the highest elevation within each polygon
>      feature using the Zonal Statistics tool: Open ArcMap and navigate to
>      ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Zonal > Zonal Statistics. This
>      generates a new raster that changes all the cell values in each
>      polygon feature to the value of the highest elevation within that
>      polygon feature. For example purposes, name this raster 'Max_Elev.'
>      The input and output parameters are as follows:
>
> A. The 'Input raster
>   or feature zone data' is the polygon feature class.
>
> B. The 'Zone
>   field' is a field in the polygon feature class that contains a unique
>   value for each polygon feature, such as OBJECTID.
>
> C. The 'Input value
>   raster' is the DEM.
>
> D. Select a name (Max_Elev) and location for the
>   'Output raster' that is generated.
>
> E. For 'Statistics type', select
>   'Maximum'.
>
> F. Make sure that 'Ignore NoData in calculations' it is
>   checked.
>
> 2. Compare the DEM to the Max_Elev raster to determine which
>      cells in the DEM correspond to the highest elevation found within each
>      polygon feature. This is done using a conditional statement in the
>      Raster Calculator: ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Map Algebra
>      Raster Calculator. The output is a raster depicting only the DEM cells
>      with the highest elevation values and all other cells set to NoData.
>      The input and output of the Raster Calculator is as follows:
>
> A. Use
>   the conditional statement: , which
>   states that if a cell in a DEM is equal to the corresponding cell in
>   Max_Elev, then set the cell value of the output raster to what is in
>   DEM. If the cell value in the DEM is not equal to the value in
>   Max_Elev, it is set to NoData in the output raster.
>
> B.
>   Provide a location and name for the Output Raster. For example, call
>   this raster 'Cell_Loc'.
>
> The output raster, Cell_Loc, may appear to not display but this is
>   because only the cells with the highest elevations actually contain
>   values. These cells may be barely visible until zoomed in. The
>   remaining cells contain NoData values and therefore by default are not
>   symbolized.
>
> 3. Convert the Cell_Loc raster to a point feature class using the Raster
>      to Point tool: ArcToolbax > Conversion Tools > From Raster > Raster to
>      Point. The input and output parameters are as follows:  A. The 'Input
>      raster' is Cell_Loc.  B. The 'Field' is 'Value'. This carries over the
>      elevation value from the cell to the point feature.  C. Select a name
>      and location for the 'Output point features'.
>
>    After the tool completes it may be necessary to change the symbology
>      of the output point features so they are clearly visible.

Comment: + 1 for a great answer (looks correct to me). You might want to add some summary details of the method so it doesn't look like "just a link".

Comment: I am close to testing so Ill let you know, looks great to me though.